# iMac Bluetooth keyboard problem with ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mac

My problem is that I install Ubuntu 13.04 on my iMac , but when I restart my computer a screen asks me to choice between OSX or Ubuntu.

The problem is I can't use the keyboard to choose OSX, so I can't log to my mac. I hope you help me to find a solution to this problem

Note: 10 seconds after the appearance of the screen, it automatically selects Ubuntu and the keyboard works fine inside Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but you cannot use a bluetooth keyboard at the GRUB boot menu. This is due to the fact that the drivers haven't been loaded.

You would have to use a USB keyboard to change what OS you wanted to boot into.

Comment: do you think there is no way to fix this problem excebt by using usb keyboard ?? :(

Comment: I am afraid not.

Comment: ok thank you .. ihope if someone else have another solution

Comment: @mahmoudyousif If your BIOS doesn't have an option for enabling bluetooth before boot then it is impossible to use a bluetooth keyboard to configure GRUB. You will need to use a USB/PSK/2 keyboard.

Comment: ((BIOS)) ???????

Comment: iMac does not have that option in the bios.