# uninstall ubuntu from imac without boot

Tags: boot, uninstall

is there any way to remove ubuntu form may imac without boot

please read this question to know what iam talking about
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310340/imac-bluetooth-keyboard-problem-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the easiest thing to do is to change the Grub order.
What you have to do is to go into your terminal and write:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
gksu grub-customizer
```

Then go to the Grub Customizer program and press the option to boot to the mac and press the up arrows on the main menu to make it go on the top of the menu.
Then restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

to remove ubuntu i think you can boot from ubuntu cd/dvd/usb instalation, then choose "try ubuntu"
then search for gparted aplication on dash,
launch it,
and you can remove the ubuntu partition, it will remove ubuntu, 
if you find a problem on boot, you can try this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair too repair boot,
i don't know on mac, but on windows it will work, i think it can solve your problem.

or you can try this
i haven't yet try this, but i think it will work, and more easy
boot from ubuntu cd, choose "try ubuntu",
install "OSuninstaller" you can follow the instruction from this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller (2nd option)